# Laravel 5 - PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

I created a laravel application and would like to deploy it to a new environment. I cloned my repository and ran 'composer install'. I also configured the .env with the new database settings. When I try to access the website there is a Server error 500. The following error is in the apache error_log.

```
[Tue Jan 26 12:52:24.876800 2016] [:error] [pid 16531] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:12499] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
[Tue Jan 26 12:55:44.302563 2016] [:error] [pid 16529] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:1615] PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Any clue what might be wrong or to look for next? Composer update runs fine:

```
server:/var/www/html$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: have you give permissions to storage folder..if not then do chmod 777 -fR path/to/storage/folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is related to the apache user rights. I fixed the issue with the following command:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R
```